# JSF Facelets passing null when using ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, nullpointerexception, facelets

I upgraded from JSF 2.1.13 -> 2.1.24 (and also tried 2.2.1).

```
<ui:repeat var="product" value="#{productList}">    
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{product!=null}">
                   <ui:repeat var="quantity"
                    value="#{priceRepository.getQuantityOptions(product).entrySet().toArray()}">
                    #{quantity}
                   </ui:repeat>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:repeat>
```

After upgrading I get a NPE when priceRepository.getQuantityOptions(product) is passed a null product. I'm not sure why its passing a null product. The productList doesn't contain any nulls and I also render only on non-null product.

Comment: In your first `ui:repeat` are you sure its just `#productList` or something like `#{bean.productList}` ?

Comment: yes I'm sure...why does this make any difference anyway?

Comment: @DD....... So did you use `productList` without any bean reference like `#{bean.productList}` before upgrading and it worked?

Comment: yes the produtList is set elsewhere using c:set. In any case...the latest version has the productList with several products with a null product a tthe end.